# Error Code: 1044: Access denied for user ' ' '@' '%' to database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect MySQL/JAWS db to deploy on Heroku but I am getting this 1044 error when trying to create a new table with my JAWS db.

I've tried granting access to user in MySQL.
I've tried re-setting and re-creating the JAWS DB in MySQL.
All my code works locally, I just can't get this issue figured out so that my deployed app on Heroku shows the SQL stuffs.

Any help?

```js
var mysql = require ('mysql');

var connection;

if (process.env.JAWSDB_URL)
{
 connection = mysql.createConnection(process.env.JAWSDB_URL);
}
else
{
 connection = mysql.createConnection(
 {
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'yourRootPassword',
  database: 'burgers_db',
 });
};


connection.connect(function(err) 
{
  if (err) 
  {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  };
  console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

module.exports = connection;
```

Error Code: 1044. Access Denied for user

Answer (score 0):

For that user dont have access to that database

provide privilege

grant all privilege on burgers_db.* to 'root'@localhost identified by 'password'